# first pair of omnis for ambient recordings?

Tags: omni, first

hello all,

so i'm thinking about buying my first pair of omnis for ambient recordings..what should i be looking for? my budget is low, around 700$...oh and btw, as far as i understand omnis are the most popular choice of mic's for ambient recordings? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got some great recordings using a matched pair of DPA 4061's (the high sensitivity version) They cost about £500 UK price, so may be in your budget. They capture fantastic detail and are small enough to take anywhere.

I bought these after they came highly recommended by the well known nature sound recordist Chris Watson.

Comment: +1 on DPA4061s. I've been planning on buying these myself. It looks like they don't go for any less than US$440, but definitely worth it for a nice quiet spaced pair. 

Comment: i own a pair of 4060's and those are not very quiet, i don't know how they compare to the 4061's but i need a fairly noisy ambient background to mask for the selfnoise of the 4060's..

Comment: Just checked this out actually, and I've made a mistake here. The 4060 is the high sensitivity version of the 4061, and it's 4060s which I own. Never found them inherently noisy though, I'll try to post a few recordings.

Comment: some recording samples would be great Mark ;)

Comment: i could make a sample recording also, nice to compare preamps and such. maybe later today, if my schedule permits..


Comment: that would be nice Arnoud ;)

Comment: didn't see your reply, will make a small recording later tonight.

Comment: ok recorded silecnce with the following setup: rme fireface uc @96 khz 24 bit. 2 levels 1. 26 dB 2. 32 dB with the onboard preamps which go from 0 dB tot 65 dB. you can hear me say test and clap my hands. second recording clipped, but it's just for background noise comparison. good luck on your decision. here's the link: http://db.tt/6RuVFrfd  

Answer (score 1):

Audio Technica 4022's are excellent mics, ~$350 each. They are quite sensitive, have very low noise (a respected person on the nature recordists mailing list measured them at 8dBA self-noise), and have a nice bright but smooth character with endless bottom end (but are very resistant to wind and handling noise). If they had detachable/moveable capsules for easier mounting in a blimp they'd almost be the perfect omni!

I own a pair and am very happy with them. Check out this site for info on mounts etc. for them :
http://diystereoboundarymics.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

ok linas,
i recorded silecnce with the following setup:
rme fireface uc @96 khz 24 bit, with the onboard preamps which go from 0 dB tot 65 dB.
Two levels:
1. 26 dB
2. 32 dB
You can hear me say test and clap my hands. Second recording clipped, but it's just for background noise comparison. good luck on your decision.

Here's the link: [link text](http://db.tt/6RuVFrfd)

Comment: thanks Arnoud, by the way, is your room acoustically treated? 

nice sample btw, noise levels are really low and imo easily removable, thou i know that rme does great audio interfaces with great preamps. 

Comment: well it is only treated with a curtains, nothing much else. normally i use a mkh-50 or 60 for recording so you wouldn't here the slapback of the acoustics.. maybe one day i'll get it better, but it's difficult stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Hi all,

I don't have anywhere quiet enough to reproduce the test Arnoud carried out, but can offer a slightly more crude, real-world example. This is a recording made from out of my window in using the 4060s into a Zoom H4 recorder with the onboard preamps at 96khz 24bit

[soundcloud]mark-durham/street-recording-test-dpa-4060[/soundcloud]

You should hear some cars going past, a few car door closes on the street just outside (recorded from 1st floor btw), some reggae emanating from a house down the street and a train pulling away in the station opposite.

Download the original Wav here:

http://soundcloud.com/mark-durham/street-recording-test-dpa-4060

For recording technique check out this picture:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/62290248@N08/6266488932/

Yes, that is a coat hanger, and those are mini rycote windjammers.

Also, as an added bonus here is the spectral frequency display of one of the car-passes:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/62290248@N08/6265959853/

You can see that there is a good amount of sound recorded up to about 30'000 hz

Hope this helps,

Mark

Comment: haha nice recording technique Mark :) 

Comment: great recording mark, nice reggea :) oh and those windjammers work ok for you? i only bought the dpa foam caps and they work fine in moderate wind conditions.. 